# React Error: Invalid DOM property `tabindex` . Did you mean `tabIndex` Creando un modal con Bbootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, modal, jsx

Cree un componente de un modal en React, compila bien, pero en el navedador en la cosola da este error:

> Warning: Invalid DOM property `tabindex`. Did you mean `tabIndex`?
>       in div (at ModalComponent.js:10)
>       in div (at ModalComponent.js:5)
>       in ModalComponent (at src/index.js:24)
>       in div (at src/index.js:23)
>       in ModalCreate (at src/index.js:32)
>       in StrictMode (at src/index.js:31)

Se que en React los atributos deben in con CamelCase pero bootstrap necesita de ese atributo asi escrito para funcionar. Este es mi codigo

```
    const ModalComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div> {/* Tiene qe haber un solo elemento Padre */}
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target={props.obj.id}>
                {props.obj.btnCallModal}
            </button>

            <div className="modal fade" id={props.obj.id} tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{props.obj.titulo}</h5>
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            {props.obj.body}
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">{props.obj.btnInModal}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

No responde directamente tu pregunta, pero te recomiendo que si quieres trabajar con Bootstrap en React, lo hagas con un framework. Para el caso, yo he trabajado sin problemas con [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/). Tu componente podría quedar así ([doc](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/)):

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react'; // "Fragment" sirve para encapsular sin usar un div
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalTitle, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';
import ... // Tus imports

const ModalComponent = (props) => {
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggleModal = () => setOpen(!isOpen);

    return (
        <Fragment> {/* Fragment encapsula sin usar un div extra */}
            <Button color="primary" onClick={toggleModal}>
                {props.obj.btnCallModal}
            </Button>

            <Modal id={props.obj.id} isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggleModal} aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <ModalHeader toggle={toggleModal}>
                    <ModalTitle>{props.obj.titulo}</ModalTitle>
                </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    {props.obj.body}
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggleModal}>Close</Button>
                    <Button color="primary">{props.obj.btnInModal}</button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
        </Fragment>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue escribir tabIndex y agregar al data-target de el boton # antes de el ID.